# SQL Table with the same fields

Tags: php, mysql, authentication

I am having a little problem with my sql/php solution.
So what I want my script/login to do is this:

When a user logged in to his account a log gets sent to sql database,
it includes: username, password, id, ip, date

I am using this script for it at the moment:

```
$fname = $_REQUEST['fname'];
$fname1 = $_REQUEST['fname1']; 
$fname2 = $ip=$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
$fname3 = $_GET['id'];
$fname4 = date('Y/m/d H:i:s');
try {
    $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=$dbname", $username, $password);
    // set the PDO error mode to exception
    $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    $sql = "INSERT INTO USERS (usern, passwd, ip, id, date)
    VALUES ('$fname', 'fname1', '$fname2', '$fname3', '$fname4')";
    // use exec() because no results are returned
    $conn->exec($sql);
```

(Don't mind the fname, i use this to make it simpler)
The problem here is when a user logs in for the first time it gets logged which is all good, but when he logs again it doesn't get saved because there is already a username like that.

Is there a way to make it possible to have multiple rows with the same username in the username field?

Comment: So my guess is that username is set to unique or as the main identifier (Primary) in your database?

Comment: Depends of your sql table configuration, don't make a usern as an unique key and youll be fine.

Comment: Make a new database field called `id`, and make it AI (Auto Increment) and make id the primary key. Remove primary/unique key from username.

Comment: An observation rather than a solutiuon but if your already using PDO why aren't you using prepared queries?

Comment: Thanks for the help guys! 
http://i.gyazo.com/25b2ca710318bb58869775178ee78db8.png
Does that mean my usern is the primary field at the moment?

Comment: Yes it does remove that index and make `id` primary key

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it guys!
Dropped the primary key and made a new column called: number
I added auto increment on this and now its all good.
Thank you all for the help!